# How to detect if screen is on/off in cordova android

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

is there a way to detect (or have an event on) the screen state of the device in Cordova ( android )
Or the sleep/wake state of the device?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not do that , have a look on cordova plugins list on [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html) website  and you will not find any plugin you can use to check the screen state

edit : if you know a way to make this happen using native java for android you can create a cordova plugin and attach it to your app but as of the currently available plugins there is not any one which can do that

Comment: I'm afraid you'r right but still hoping someone has done it before me

Answer (score -1):

There is some property like "mLockScreenShown" & "mWakefulness" in dumpsys activity by which you can get device lock screen status. If you run `dumpsys activity` command in adb shell you will get almost everything about androd activity. Here below is the complete Java API which will give you screen state of android device.

```
 public static String getScreenState() throws IOException {
    Process process = null;
    BufferedReader buffRead;
    String processString = "";
    int sleepMode = -1;
    int awakeMode = -1;
    String screenState = "";

    try {
        String command = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "tools" + File.separator
                + "adb.exe shell dumpsys activity | grep mLockScreenShown";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 1024);
        while ((processString = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
            if (processString.split("mSleeping=").length > 1) {
                if (processString.split("mSleeping=")[1].startsWith("true"))
                    sleepMode = 0;
                else if (processString.split("mSleeping=")[1].startsWith("false"))
                    sleepMode = 1;
            }
        }

        try {
            command = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "tools" + File.separator
                    + "adb.exe shell dumpsys activity | grep mWakefulness";
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        processString = "";
        buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 1024);
        while ((processString = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
            if (processString.split("mWakefulness=").length > 1) {
                if (processString.split("mWakefulness=")[1].startsWith("Awake"))
                    awakeMode = 0;
                else if (processString.split("mWakefulness=")[1].startsWith("Asleep")
                        || processString.split("mWakefulness=")[1].startsWith("Dozing"))
                    awakeMode = 1;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (sleepMode == 0 && awakeMode == 1) {
        screenState = "SCREEN_OFF";
    } else if (sleepMode == 0 && awakeMode == 0) {
        screenState = "SCREEN_LOCK";
    } else if (sleepMode == 1 && awakeMode == 0) {
        screenState = "SCREEN_ON";
    }

    return screenState;
}
```